# How can I connect to my VM via SSH from outside the network

Tags: networking, ssh, debian, vmware

So I have a Windows PC on which runs a VMware with Debian. I'm using NAT, because i don't have any other network interface. So is this even possible with NAT? I want to connect from let's say another network and another pc to my debian which runs on my windows. Do I need to forward some port from my windows pc to my vm? Is this possible? 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have three options

- If you use a home router, the most forward-looking way is to reconfigure your VM to use a seperate IP address and then do a port forward for port 22 to this seperate IP address on your router. This allows your setup to still work, if you chose to run your VM on a different host
- If you do not use a home router (i.e. your windows machine carries the public IP address) you need to port forward inside Windows (or VMware)
- If you do use a home router and want to stay with the NATed network for the VM you need to set up 2 port forwards: Once in the router (forwarding to the windows host) and another inside the windows host to the VM

Comment: your 3d option seems like it's right one for me. Can you move me in the right direction on how to setup those two forwards? So on my router I will open Port 22 to my Windows IP, and then what port do I have to route to my vw and where? Never really used windows port forwarding, only router forwarding

Comment: So sorry, I never use Windows or VMware at all any longer and so don't know. I do guess, that this would be something to setup in VMware, not in Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I used `Virtual Network Editor` for `VMware Workstation 15.x Player` to route my host port 22 to my guest ip and port ;) Thanks